# Finding the unique identifyer for a row with NA in a particular column in R

Tags: r

I have data in the following format:

```
ID  Species Side_of_boat
1   spA     Port
2   spB     Starboard
3   spA     NA
```

I would like to write a line of code that gives me the unique ID for all rows that have NA in 'side of boat'.

I have tried:

```
unique(df$ID[df$side_of_boat == "NA"])
```

But it doesn't give me the output I want. I would like the output to be:

```
"3"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
unique(df$ID[is.na(df$Side_of_boat)])
```

instead. `NA` is a special value in R and also has its own special function `is.na()` to test if an entry is `NA`. Check `?NA` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

`#Method1`

`n <- which(is.na(df$side_of_boat))`

you can also use `*apply` with this, e.g.

`lapply(apply(df$side_of_boat, 1, function(x) which(!is.na(x)) ) , paste, collapse=", ")`

`#Method 2`

`new_DF <- subset(df, is.na(df$side_of_boat))`

`#Method 3`

You could also write a function to do this for you:

`getNa <- function(dfrm) lapply(dfrm, function(x) which(is.na(x) ) )`

`#Note`
In case you have NA character values, first run

`df$side_of_boat[df$side_of_boat=='NA'] <- NA`

Comment: +1 because Method 1 and 3 also work in case `ID` is not unique (which is not rhe case in the given example, but could be in general).

Comment: Regarding #1: what if ID started with 2 or any number other than 1 or generally if it were not the sequence 1:n? And method 2: the subset is right, but it doesn't generate the desired output, since the OP asked a) for only the ID and b) they only wanted unique values.

Comment: I don't think that would cause a problem for #1. I use it all the time and my ID's usually begin with letters then have random numbers. It's just testing if a cell is NA or not. Method 2 is just giving an additional way to get NA rows that will hopefully be useful to future readers, but yes, it does provide complete records.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df$ID[which(is.na(df$Side_of_Boat))]
```

It should give you a vector of the ID's regardless of them being numbers or characters